# Kendo UI TreeView - how do I populate different children nodes for each parent node?

Tags: jquery, treeview, kendo-ui

The following populates the parent and children nodes. The issue is that the children are all the same for all the parent nodes. I need to populate the children nodes based on an "id" of the parent. How would I go about doing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Kendo UI Test</title>
        <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="treeview"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var notifications = {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://..."
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        Notification: "Notification",
                        hasChildren: false
                    }
                }
            };

            var notificationTypes = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://..."
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        NotificationType: "NotificationType",
                        hasChildren: true,
                        children: notifications
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: notificationTypes,
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true
                },
                dataTextField: ["NotificationType", "Notification"]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The children nodes are gathered by an API call, as such:

```
/api/notifications/{id}
```

Each parent has a different ID that needs to be matched with the children.

I'm really lost on this one and would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it:

```
function CreateNotificationTree(userId)
{
    debugger;
    var data = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../api/notifications/byuserid/" + userId,
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "notifications"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: data,
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataUrlField: "LinksTo",
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataTextField: ["notificationType", "NotificationDesc"],
        select: treeviewSelect
    });

    function treeviewSelect(e)
    {
        var node = this.dataItem(e.node);
        window.open(node.NotificationLink, "_self");
    }
}
```